# Relevance of User Agent in HTTP Requests

Tags: android, ios, http, http-headers

My friend implemented an HTTP POST request in iOS and it was working fine.

I have tried to implement the same in Android, but it doesn't work **until I added the User Agent** (I got it with the help of some sniffer tools).

But in iOS he is not specifying the User Agent.

So,

- What is the relevance of User Agent in HTTP Request?
- Why is it not consistent between iOS and Android?

Comment: what http client are you using ? or some 3rd party library?

Comment: I have tried it with both DefaultHTTPClient and HTTPUrlConnection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

iOS already specifies the User Agent by default. The user agent sent with NSURLConnection on iOS is

```
User-Agent: <app identifier>/<app version> CFNetwork/609.1.4 Darwin/12.4.0
```

where `<app identifier>` is your bundle ID (e.g. com.company.app) and `<app version>` is the current version of your app. Apparently, as you experience, Android does not set a default User Agent with (non-browser) HTTP requests.

The server can use this information to adapt its response to the client's needs; e.g. showing a mobile version of a webpage instead of a desktop version, or just don't return anything (to prevent simple screen scraping).

Comment: perfect answer brother